# htaccess too many redirects - old_file to new_file on the same domain

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, browser, hosting

I try solutions which I found on stackoverflow but with no luck...

### Here's my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com[nc]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysitesite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Redirect 301 old_file.html new_file.html
```

==============================

I have no idea what's wrong but browsers said "too many redirects".
Please look and show me what's wrong.

Comment: Is that all you have in your .htaccess? What is URL you're entering in browser? Did you try clearing browser cache?

Comment: Yes, that's all I have in my htacces - force www, 404 page and redirect from old to new file. I tried browsers incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution:

> RewriteRule ^old_site.html$ http://example.com/new_site.html